# unable to open traefik dashboard

Tags: traefik, traefik-routers

i am trying to access the traefik dashboard using the url `https://example.com/dashboard`, but i keep getting a 404 not found error.

here is my `tls.toml` file

```
[http.routers]
  [http.routers.traefik]
    rule = "Host(`example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)"
    middlewares = [] 
    service = "api@internal"
    entryPoints = ["traefik"]
    [http.routers.traefik.tls]
      options = "default"
```

is there something wrong with my rule definition?